# How to run scheduled task in the background in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Was successful in using [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html), works on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8.

Comment: There's Task Scheduler in Win 7/8 Control Panel/Admin tools

Comment: @Dan-o - Though it's hard to get the Task Scheduler to run something without a visible window.  Used to be you could do it on W98, I think, but they put took away the obvious option on Vista.

Comment: @Luke, No errors at all. It seems that hstart is not compatible with Windows 8.

Comment: @Dan-o Task Scheduler do has option called "Run in background" but the command prompt is showing up even that option is checked. It is same is Windows 7 also. Don't have idea why that option is for.

Comment: I don't know anything about hstart, but this looks like a great alternative:  http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

Comment: Try selecting the **Run whether user is logged on or not** instead of **Run only when user is logged on** radio button.